# How to check specific string sequance using the regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to create a regular expression to extract company details from a list of companies, but is facing difficulty because some companies have their mobile number listed before the company code and some have it listed after. They only want to match companies that have the mobile number listed after the company code and have tried using a look ahead in the regular expression but it hasn't been successful.

my regex syntax

`details of the company:(?<address>[^\n\r]*)\b(?!.*mobile).*(company-code:)(.*?)(mobile:)(.*?)`

strings to be checked:

details of the company: name:xyz, company-code:100, mobile:123

details of the company: name:xyz, mobile:12345, company-code:100

Comment: So far, it doesn't look like your expression would match anything at all in the sample data you have given? https://regex101.com/r/ruDwQL/1

Comment: @CBroe,  yeah, because i think the negative look ahead is not well written by me. I made some edits , when i remove negative look ahead it is working well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at it a little differently. From a more generic perspective your strings have a pattern of `prefix: field1:value1, field2:value2, ...`. So you can focus on matching the field:value pairs. Using `preg_match_all()` you can fetch all matches as sets.

```php
$data = [
  'details of the company: name:xyz, company-code:100, mobile:123',
  'details of the company: name:xyz, mobile:12345, company-code:100',
];

$pattern = '((?<field>[a-z-]+):\s*(?<value>[^,:]+)(?:,|$))';

$companies = [];
foreach ($data as $subject) {
    if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        // new company array
        $company = [];
        // iterate and add found fields
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $company[$match['field']] = $match['value'];
        }
        // add company array to list
        $companies[] = $company;
    } 
}

var_dump($companies);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "xyz"
    ["company-code"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["mobile"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "xyz"
    ["mobile"]=>
    string(5) "12345"
    ["company-code"]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
```

Another solution would be to use string functions. Remove all unnecessary parts from the subject and then split it.

```php
$prefix = 'details of the company: ';

$companies = [];
foreach ($data as $subject) {
    $subject = substr($subject, strlen($prefix));
    $pairs = explode(',', $subject);
    $company = [];
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        [$field, $value] = explode(':', $pair);
        $company[trim($field)] = trim($value);
    }
    $companies[] = $company;
}

var_dump($companies);
```